# Why it doesn't swap two integers in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int A[6]={3,7,9,4,6,1};
    int max;
    max = A[0];
    for(int i=0; i< 6; i++)
    {
        if(A[i] > max)
        {
            max = A[i];
        }

    }
    //cout << max <<"\n";

    int temp;
    temp=A[0];
    A[0]=max;
    max = temp;

    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        cout << A[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to swap the maximum value with the first one in the decared array but it only replaces 1st value with maximum while maximum value is also retained at its position.

Comment: You're swapping it with `max`. That's not a location in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is slightly wrong. You are actually swapping the values of variable `max` instead of the element with the `max` value.

If you want to swap the element with max value, keep track of its position, like this:

```
 if(A[i] > max)
    {
        max = A[i];
        pos = i;
    }
```

And while swapping, use it as follows:

```
int temp;
temp=A[0];
A[0]=A[pos];
A[pos] = temp;
```

Note: An alternative way is to use pointers, this is just a simple non-pointer method.

Answer (score 0):

You're swapping `A[0]` with the variable `max`, not the array element you took its value from.

You could make `max` a pointer, so that it can be used to access the array element; or you could remember the array index that the value came from. Or you could use the standard library:

```
swap(A[0], *max_element(begin(A), end(A)));
```

Answer (score 0):

`max` is just an integer, it doesn't point to any location in the array, so assigning it will not change the array. You could change `max` to be a pointer so that changing it changes the value it points to:

```
int main()
{
    int A[6]={3,7,9,4,6,1};
    int *max;
    max = &A[0];
    for(int i=0; i< 6; i++)
    {
        if(A[i] > *max)
        {
            max = &A[i];
        }   
    }

    int temp;
    temp=A[0];
    A[0]=*max;
    *max = temp;

    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        cout << A[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```